# Plotting multiple lines from columns of Dataframe (python/pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, astronomy

I have large (~1 million) data set that looks something like this...

```
Age    Wavelength    Luminosity

1      96            100
1      97            150
1      98            100
2      96.5          90
2      97            160
2      97.5          120
...
```

I have it in a dataframe currently and want to plot wavelength vs Luminosity for all age groups. How do i get plots for each age on one graph?

Comment: This looks like not a stackoverflow question. what about posting your question to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @Andrés when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: How is this even remotely on-topic on Programmers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.plot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.plot.html)

```
In[1]: import pandas as pd

In[2]: import numpy as np

In[3]: dataset = pd.DataFrame({"Age": np.random.random_integers(1, 5, 100), "Wavelength": np.random.uniform(90, 100, 100), "Luminosity": np.random.random_integers(5, 15, 100) * 10})

In[4]: dataset.groupby("Age").plot(x="Wavelength", y="Luminosity", kind="scatter")
Out[4]: 
Age
1    Axes(0.125,0.1;0.775x0.8)
2    Axes(0.125,0.1;0.775x0.8)
3    Axes(0.125,0.1;0.775x0.8)
4    Axes(0.125,0.1;0.775x0.8)
5    Axes(0.125,0.1;0.775x0.8)
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to get all of these onto one graph?

Comment: The `plot` function returns an `matplotlib` `AxesSubplot` object. So you could work with `matplotlib` subplot grid and this axis object. I haven't tried it though.